# what is umrah condition for old women if she had no mehram?

Tags: non-mahram, mahram, umrah

There is a women in my neighbor and she is unmarried old lady of 60 years and have enough money to perform umrah but have no mahram with her. so what is the condition for her? she can perform umrah with group of ladies or not?

Comment: https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/33135/13438 may be helpful and relevant.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Saudi law](https://www.saudiembassy.net/hajj-requirements):

> Women over the age of forty-five (45) may travel without a Mahram with an organized group, They must, however submits a no objection letter from her husband, son or brother authorizing her to travel for Hajj with the named group. This letter should be notarized.

Perhaps a notarised letter from her local masjid pointing out the situation will suffice, however there have been some rulings over the years from various jurists and perhaps also in Hadith (but I can't verify this, I can't find it) that if a woman has no mahram at all, then she is effectively exempt from hajj. I'd say if the letter does not work, then there's nothing that can be done, and of course Allah is the most merciful, what can she do?

Comment: Is Saudi law representing Islam by now?

Comment: Are you asking if I'm a Wahhabi? It doesn't matter if I am or not (I'm not), but Mecca is in Saudi Arabia, unless you follow their laws it doesn't matter. If 
 you want to go on hajj, and you're a woman, and they say the rules for not having mahram are this or that, then guess what, that's how it is... for now.

Comment: I think my comment is very straightforward this site is entitled IslamSE not local law SE. Having said this I don't deny that this answer might be helpful for OP and others even if it lacks an Islamic explanation.

Comment: I apologise, I misunderstood. I tried to give answers to both, but as I stated I couldn't find the hadith I was looking for so I couldn't verify that aspect, only really what the Saudi state says.