# Can i travel without a mahram?

Tags: travelling, mahram

Just like most females, I don't have a wali or a male mahram that I can travel with. Is it permissible to travel by myself or with a female mahram?

Comment: This question could help you: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/33135/how-do-unmarried-women-with-no-mahram-go-on-a-pilgrimage-to-mecca Especially the answer is the most valuable for you.

Comment: Be aware that travel is unlike travel and so are the rulings: You should specify reason, duration of the travel or distance, desteny and where and with whom will you stay first.